# Twitter Bootstrap vs. Semantic UI

Tags: bootstrap-3, semantic-ui

Alguém pode dizer qual é a diferença entre essas bibliotecas?

Eu vi que Semantic tem mais vantagens do que Bootstrap mas seria bom saber se alguém conhece as duas e sabe comparar características, soluções ou API.

http://semantic-ui.com/
http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Matheus, editei a pergunta para ser mais técnica e específica. Perguntar se deves usar uma ou outra gera respostas de opinião e está fora do tópico.

Comment: Obrigado por editar. Preciso realmente saber as diferenças entre os 2

Comment: Sinceramente eu prefiro o Semantic pra tudo; porém o Bootstrap tem muito mais themes Semantic não suporta Angular e é um ponto super negativo :/

Comment: Leia: [A Collection of best front End frameworks for Faster&Easier Web Development](http://usablica.github.io/front-end-frameworks/compare.html), ou só veja, tanto faz.

Comment: Bootstrap é único que aceita sass e lesss, bom saber